# Brouwer vs. Cantor

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory

Brouwer criticises Cantor e.g. in [Intuitionistiche Mengenlehre](http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00014747.pdf). Is there a link or reference to some streamlined modern account of Brouwer's ideas?

Comment: It is a common idea that early intuitionism propounds the point of view that there are only denumerably many objects. It would be nice to have an accessible reference for this.

Comment: When you say "streamlined modern account", do you mean a mathematicized account: one written in modern-day mathematical language? Or do you mean more of a retrospective that comments on what Brouwer said and published?

Comment: If you want something streamlined and modern, I wouldn't look at Brouwer's intuitionist ideas.

Comment: @Todd I am interested in in what you take to be a mathematicized account.

Comment: @Matt I am interested in a streamlined modern account of Brouwer, and not an account of Brouwer as streamlined or modern.

Comment: Well, for example, what has come to be known as the Brouwer-Heyting-Kolmogorov interpretation was (I think) somewhat nebulous and philosophical in the beginning, but is made rigorous post Brouwer in terms of e.g. Kleene realizability and the accompanying construction of triposes and toposes. (Of course that's just one aspect of Brouwer's thought; it's not meant to cover everything.)

Comment: I am not suggesting that there are not many important ideas with Brouwer. However, here I am interested in the status of the common (mis?)conception that Brouwer had an intuitionistic criticism of Cantor's idea that there are uncountable sets.

Answer (score 5):

The life story and the scientific biography of Brouwer are the subject of the book [L.E.J. Brouwer – Topologist, Intuitionist, Philosopher: How Mathematics Is Rooted in Life](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447146158) by Dirk van Dalen.

Comment: Does the book treat the topic? I would prefer something available online at least by means of JSTOR.

Answer (score 4):

Troelstra is a well-known exponent of intuitionism. Here are two online articles that contain philosophical and historical material that may be useful to you:

- [Remarks on Intuitionism and the Philosophy of Mathematics](https://www.illc.uva.nl/Research/Publications/Reports/X-1990-01.text.pdf)
- [History of constructivism in the 20th century](https://www.illc.uva.nl/Research/Publications/Reports/ML-1991-05.text.pdf)

You might check out particularly section 6 (of the latter article) on Brouwer's intuitionistic analysis and account of the continuum, and some of the subsequent history.

Comment: Thanks for these. I have been aware of Troelstra and others as famous exponents of intuitionism. But your reference here does not to me seem to locate something that vindicates that Brouwer had ideas which somehow successfully (justifies by its own philosophy, as it were) evaded Cantor's idea that there are uncountable sets.

Comment: Yes, I think the story must be complicated (and unfortunately I'm no scholar here). The second reference touches on Brouwer's notion of choice sequences which were apparently crucial to his conception of the continuum. Thus (and I think this gets closer to your concerns), my rough reading is that Brouwer could not accept the idea of the continuum as a "bag of points" which could be considered in isolation, but considered that the continuum had to be given as a whole (and so he rejected the classical constructions of the continuum).

Comment: What's a little puzzling to me about this discussion is that, to the best of my knowledge, contemporary mathematicians accept Cantor's argument that a set cannot map onto its power set as completely consistent with intuitionistic principles (I am not considering objections coming from predicative mathematics, where power sets are rejected).

Comment: I am puzzled for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Laura Crosilla has a rather comprehensive [bibliography](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmtmlcr/Bibliography/) for constructive and intuitionistic set theory on her website. Including her SEP entry on the subject. Some of the papers, like Grayson's on Heyting-valued models, actually develop some mathematics inside the set theory they define.

This might be relevant re what intuitionism has to propose in the stead of Cantor's development.

Comment: Theanks. It seems to me that Laura Crosilla deals with modern intuitionistic set theories which either (1) do not have the power set or (2) accept Cantor's theorem that there are uncountable sets. I am looking for something with Brouwer that was geared to avoid uncountable sets.